# What is the maximum / minimum phase shift in the Dual Active Bridge converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, phase-shift, dual-active-bridge

Learning Dual Active Bridge Converter from this [article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9448428).

Recommended work area to achieve ZVS

[image]

There is a formula for calculating phase shift limits
[image]

Where M = N*Vout/Vin, N = 1.6

In the article, I saw a mention of choosing a maximum phase shift of no more than 0.4, since there may be problems in control further.
Are there minimum phase shift boundaries?

If the input is 800V, the output is 500V with a phase shift of 0 radians. And I want to get 495 volts? Then the phase shift will be 0.005 or, for example, I want to get 499 Volts at the output, where the phase shift will be generally 0.00099. Are such phase shift values ​​acceptable?

Also, what is the correct way to calculate the maximum phase shift value?
With an input voltage value of 800V, and at the output of 380V I get a phase shift of 0.12 radians. In the article, as far as I understand, at the same voltage values ​​​​there was a value of 0.35. The solution is not entirely clear. Or do they make a certain stock?

P.s. if you want to check the calculation. Phase shift [calculator code](https://pastebin.com/AEVhNHLD) (PHP), paste into the [emulator](http://phptester.net/).

Comment: It seems likely that you would get a more detailed answer by simulating it and trying out different scenarios. Not difficult to do (even with phase shifted PWM drive).

Comment: @Andyaka, Thank you for the answer! I figured out the DAB model in LTspice, as a result, I had a question: can DAB in one design both lower and raise the voltage relative to the input? I checked the model, where by changing the phase shift, the voltage only changes in the direction of decrease. If it requires a separate question, I will do it.

Comment: I think you would need to show the circuit and, maybe ask a new question